# UITableViewStyleGrouped with a right angle

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

When I create table view with

```
myTableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 400) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
```

table view has rounded corners, but I wanna have right angle (so table view cell should look like rectangles, but table view still should have many sections).

The question  is: how can I create table view with many sections and right angles?

Comment: dont use grouped tableview use simple style or use images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the TableView datasource.  In the cellForRowAtIndexPath you can set the background of the cell to be blank...

```
cell.backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero()];
```

Then you can put an image or rect or whatever in the back of the cell.

You could even create a new UIView and put that in place of the backgroundView.

Then you can put whatever you want in it, images, labels, etc... and they will go behind the content of the cell.

The rounded corners of the cell in grouped style is just an image so can be replaced by you.

Comment: I used this: cell=[[[CustomCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]autorelease];
        cell.backgroundView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.bounds] autorelease];
        cell.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

Answer (score 1):

set image as a background image to cell and give the backgroundcolor of `UITableView` to `clearColor` and set image like bellow..

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
     ///write your code..
       UIImageView *img = [[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 45)] autorelease]; // set frame as your cell frame
      img.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImageName"];
      cell.backgroundView = img;
    ////write your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Sections you can code a delegate method like

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
```

{

```
// Return the number of sections.
return 1;//how many sections you want you can write a value after return type
```

}

Comment: I should have many sections. And how does it solve issue with right andle?

Answer (score 0):

Best way I found to make the corners right angled is to set the background view to nil and then put a view in it.

```
[cell setBackgroundView:nil];

cell.backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
```